# Как такая же схема будет работать с сессией?

Tags: c#, json, парсер, сессия

Есть файл, который я получаю из Яндекса для домена, он в формате `JSON`, и я его парсю и заливаю в таблицу на веб страничке. Как мне организовать с ним работу. Слышал про хранение данных в сессии. Сейчас у меня такая схема работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это будет выглядеть с сессией ? Как я понимаю сессию `JSON` парсится заранее  и загружается в переменную и уже при открытии странички из этой переменной выгружается в таблицу. И вообще как это реализовать не совсем понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понял вопроса, но хоть чем то помогу.
Хранить данные в сессии очнеь просто:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["любое имя параметра"] = "любые данные"
```